# Any way to iterate over controls of a view?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I wanted to get all of the textfields for my view, but I can't figure out if there's a control tree property somewhere that would allow me to iterate over the set of controls. I'm positive it's there somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocoa uses its view hierarchy for event handling. I don't think there is a separate tree for controls only. However, you can easily inspect the view hierarchy through the `subviews` property and the `superview` property. Use introspection to find out the controls you want to work on (e.g., `[aView isKindOf:[UITextField class]]`).

An alternative is to give tags to your controls and ask its superview to give the reference to a control with a specified tag.

Comment: That tag bit is clever, I really like that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a better way, but when I've needed to do something like this, I've used a for each loop over the subviews and then checked for the needed class (so test each view in the loop if it is a UITextView in this case, then perform the needed actions on it).